# Passing async loaded data from router component to child components in ng1

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, binding, components

I have this dilemma that I'm facing atm...In my app the routed component uses a service to loads some async data form the db, then I want to pass that data to child components.

The thing is that the child controller does not get that data while the view gets it...The solution I'm using now is to resolve that data prior to route component load and pass it as a resolve on the route, then the data gets propagated to the child controllers of the route controller.

Is there any other way to do this so that the child components get the async data that parent controllers load?
Thanks.

Comment: Scopes are prototypically inherited so typically can access the parent scope properties from a child but to be sure the asynchronous operation completed before the controller is created a resolve is the right way to go.

Comment: Alternative is to use a factory to store the results and reference that factories data both places